# Error: [MissingConnectionException] Database connection "Mysql" is missing, or could not be created + cakephp 2.x

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I got an error during placing order. Order placed half and after that i got error. I checked **error.log** file i found,

```
013-11-25 16:35:07 Error: [MissingConnectionException] Database connection "Mysql" is missing, or could not be created.
#0 /usr/local/pem/vhosts/262731/webspace/httpdocs/parceldirect.ie/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php(261): Mysql->connect()
#1 /usr/local/pem/vhosts/262731/webspace/httpdocs/parceldirect.ie/lib/Cake/Model/ConnectionManager.php(101): DboSource->__construct(Array)
#2 /usr/local/pem/vhosts/262731/webspace/httpdocs/parceldirect.ie/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php(3164): ConnectionManager::getDataSource('default')
#3 /usr/local/pem/vhosts/262731/webspace/httpdocs/parceldirect.ie/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php(1096): Model->setDataSource('default')
#4 /usr/local/pem/vhosts/262731/webspace/httpdocs/parceldirect.ie/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php(3186): Model->setSource('baskets')
#5 /usr/local/pem/vhosts/262731/webspace/httpdocs/parceldirect.ie/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php(2637): Model->getDataSource()
#6 /usr/local/pem/vhosts/262731/webspace/httpdocs/parceldirect.ie/app/Model/Basket.php(24): Model->find('first', Array)
#7 /usr/local/pem/vhosts/262731/webspace/httpdocs/parceldirect.ie/app/Controller/AppController.php(53): Basket->getSessionDetails('c71b56ada66fd45...')
#8 [internal function]: AppController->beforeFilter(Object(CakeEvent))
#9 /usr/local/pem/vhosts/262731/webspace/httpdocs/parceldirect.ie/lib/Cake/Event/CakeEventManager.php(246): call_user_func(Array, Object(CakeEvent))
#10 /usr/local/pem/vhosts/262731/webspace/httpdocs/parceldirect.ie/lib/Cake/Controller/Controller.php(669): CakeEventManager->dispatch(Object(CakeEvent))
#11 /usr/local/pem/vhosts/262731/webspace/httpdocs/parceldirect.ie/lib/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php(183): Controller->startupProcess()
#12 /usr/local/pem/vhosts/262731/webspace/httpdocs/parceldirect.ie/lib/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php(161): Dispatcher->_invoke(Object(IndexController), Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#13 /usr/local/pem/vhosts/262731/webspace/httpdocs/parceldirect.ie/app/webroot/index.php(92): Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#14 {main}
```

Can anyone suggest me what is the issue with connection? Was server down during order process and got that error? Or any other issue?

Comment: is this the issue only with Basket Model ?

Comment: no its not only for Basket Model because i have place 200+ order but this is first time i got this issue

Comment: I mean rest of the application is working okay or you are getting same error

Comment: Yes, Rest of the application working fine. Its around 3 month I lived the website and i got this error first time. After this error, Doing same procedure but all working things working fine. Is this server down issue?

Comment: Please check the database and make check the table is there

Comment: Yes all tables are fine. I do same procedure of order but its working fine.